# Sending shutdown command on specific switch port interfaces through ansible using cli_command module

Tags: ansible

here is my _main.yml _

```yaml
---

- name: run show version on switch
  cli_command:
    command: show version
  register: show

- name: print command output
  debug: var=show.stdout_lines[0]

- name: Shutdown TOR-A port
  cli_command:
    command: "{{ item }}"
  register: command_output

  with_items:

    - "config"
    - "interface Tengigabitethernet 0/35"
    - "shutdown"

- name: Debug command output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ command_output }}"
```

How do I access port 36,7,8, and so on on the same switch and issue shutdown on mentioned switch ports in a sequence?

I have to repeat the same activity for another switch TOR-B , the task should be identical.However , I am not sure how to dynamically achieve the objective in one yaml file.Any help will be appreciated!

The switch credentials are saved in hosts file

Comment: Is the current example shutting down port 35 ? Does it work as expected ? Are you going to shutdown the same ports on all switches or do you have different ports per switch ? Do you need to issue a config command for each port shutdown or is it enough to have it once per switch ?

Comment: @Zeitounator yes above script works fine and I have verified logging into the switch. Once we are in  switch config mode ,we need not necessarily send config command again .It can be sequence of interface something like "interface Tengigabitethernet 0/36" 
shutdown
"interface Tengigabitethernet 0/7"
shutdown
"interface Tengigabitethernet 0/8"
shudown

Answer (score 0):

The following should basically do the job (Note: I do not have any cli compatible switch to test against).

Create a `shutdown_ports.yml` file with the following content. This file can be at the same level of you playbook, or inside your `tasks` folder in role if you include it from there.

```yaml
---
- name: "shutdown port"
  cli_command:
    command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "interface Tengigabitethernet 0/{{ port }}"
    - "shutdown"
```

Use that file as an include in a loop like in the following playbook example

```yaml
---
- name: shutdown same ports on all switches
  hosts: group_containing_my_switches

  vars:
    shutdown_ports:
      - 35
      - 36
      - 7
      - 8

  tasks:
    - name: switch to config mode
      cli_command:
        command: config

    - name: shutdown all referenced ports
      include_tasks: shutdown_ports.yml
      loop: "{{ shutdown_ports }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: port
```

---

An other possible solution is to dynamically create an array containing all command to send and play all those in a loop. Example playbook again

```yaml
---
- name: shutdown same ports on all switches
  hosts: group_containing_my_switches

  vars:
    shutdown_ports:
      - 35
      - 36
      - 7
      - 8
  
  tasks:
    - name: Add config mode as first command
      set_fact:
        cli_switch_commands:
          - config

    - name: Add commands for each port shutdown
      vars:
        current_port_command: "interface Tengigabitethernet 0/{{ item }}"
      set_fact:
        cli_switch_commands: "{{ cli_switch_commands + [current_port_command, 'shutdown'] }}"
      loop: "{{ shutdown_ports }}"

     - name: Send all commands to switch
       cli_command:
         command: "{{ item }}"
       loop: "{{ cli_switch_commands }}"
```